# Update item in django DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to understand django better and have worked on the following simple app.
I am trying to have (recurring) tasks which belong to a certain project. At the top of a task list I will have the task that has not been performed for the longest time. Clicking on a task will mean that it is/has been performed and I want to update the field `last_performed` to today and then reload the view. So far I have solved it like this.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_performed = models.DateField('last time peformed')
```

The template for the task list is

```
<h1>{{ project.project_name }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for task in project.task_set.all %}
    <li>{{ task.task_name }} ({{ task.last_performed }}) 
    <a href="{% url 'update' 1 task.task_name %}">Perform</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and the view.py

```
class ProjectView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'tasks/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'project_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.all()

class TaskView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'tasks/detail.html'

def update(request, project_id, task_name):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    task = project.task_set.filter(task_name=task_name).first()
    task.last_performed = timezone.now().today()
    task.save()
    return render(request, 'tasks/detail.html', {'project': project})
```

I have the following patterns

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.TaskView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/<task_name>/', views.update, name='update'),
]
```

Now my question is as follows. While this works, I was wondering what would be a clean solution for the `update`. The point is that code has some lines in common with the `TaskView` if I would write it as a method as follows:

```
def detail(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    return render(request, 'tasks/detail.html', {'project': project})
```

Also is there a way to update it, without having to change the path to `tasks/1/clean/` for example?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd mix class-based and function-based views; that's a bit confusing. As for your question, though, you should be able to override `TaskView.get` to run your query and then call `super().get(...)` method to retain its functionality. Also, your `ProjectView` can [set `model = Project`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) rather than overriding `get_queryset`.

Comment: @kungphu yeah not sure why I had the get_queryset, thanks! Thanks for your suggestion, overriding works! I assume there is not way to omit a path like ```tasks/1/clean/```?

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Sorry, I don't know what you mean about omitting a path, though. You don't have to redirect or anything to just update and save the model with an overridden `get(...)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my last question, which now seems very trivial to me, I just overrode the ```post`` method as follows

```
    def post(self, request, pk):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
        task_name = request.POST.get('task', None)
        task = project.task_set.filter(task_name=task_name).first()
        task.last_performed = timezone.now().today()
        task.save()
        return super().get(request, pk)
```

This way when I 'perform a task', I stay at the url `tasks/1/`. Thanks to @kungphu for the hints.